# cmath function that adds and multiplies at once x*y+z

Tags: c++, c, cmath

Is there a function in the `cmath` library which given 3 numbers `x`, `y` and `z` returns `x*y+z`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`fma` which stands for Fused Multiply Add was introduced in C99 and [C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fma):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    assert(std::fabs(std::fma(2.0, 3.0, 4.0) - (2.0 * 3.0 + 4.0)) < 0.001);
}
```

Probable rationales:

- [IEEE 754-2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) seems to have added support for the operation, requiring that it be done with a single rounding instead of two.

  Thanks to @Lưu for bringing it up in the comment.
- some popular archs such as [ARM and x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation) have one cycle fma instructions, so in theory an arch optimized compilers / stdlibs could use those.

  I do not know if in practice modern compilers are doing this optimization already.

  For integers on X86, FMA could already be done with the LEA instruction: I think the innovation is the fact that it uses double.

Comment: The hardware FMA is present only in the newest Intel CPUs and some older AMD CPUs. There's a dot product instruction in SSE4.1 that could used here as well together with a horizontal add.

Comment: Couldn't it be faked on intel with LEA on older architectures? At least for ints.

Comment: @Charlie I think so. Probably the "innovation" is for the doubles.

Comment: I would be surprised if using the library function doesn't actually lead to worse results from the optimizer.

Comment: @Charlie the difference between [fma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation) and a normal multiplication followed by addition is that fma fused the 2 operations together, result in only a single rounding, whereas the other must do 2 roundings, therefore fma will be more correct. Of course with ints there's no rounding so the result will be the same. Most compilers nowadays will be smart enough to use LEA if possible